# Disable Redirect to Product Page on Search Results Page in WooCommerce

Tags: search, plugins

In WooCommerce if you search for a product and there is only one search result then WooCommerce will redirect you directly to the product page. If I want to add some fancy styling to the search results page is there a way I can disable this default functionality?

Comment: Please ask at the [WooCommerce Community Forums](http://community.woocommerce.com/).

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is totally possible. WooCommerce includes a [handy filter](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/v2.0.13/woocommerce-functions.php#L70-L78) that you can manipulate to disable that redirect so the user will continue onto the search results page as per normal.

If you add this line of code to your `functions.php` file it will disable the redirect functionality.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_redirect_single_search_result', '__return_false' );
```

Permalink to gist: https://gist.github.com/BFTrick/6429700